# If functional components don't have a constructor, how does enzymes find function work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

My understanding of the invocation of functional components and class based components is as follow:

```
const FunctionalComponent = Foo()
const ClassComponent = new Bar()
```

I was going through enzymes documentation and their `find` selector accepts a components constructor as a selector.

How does this work when functional components don't have a constructor?

Comment: Have you tried creating a test with enzyme and a functional component and seeing if find() works?

Comment: Yep. It works. I'm just not sure how. I looked at the element skeleton and there isn't any identifier with that node to specify what it is apart from the fiber node id.